# Binding and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind a TextBlock using `INotifyPropertyChanged` event. But it is not updating anything to the `TextBlock`. The `TextBlock` is blank. My goal is to update the status of items which are displayed in different rows. I need to update the `TextBlock`'s text and color based on the status.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
public class ItemStatus : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string itemStatus;
    Brush itemStatusColor;

    public string ItemStatus
    {
        get { return itemStatus; }
        set
        {
            itemStatus = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ItemStatus");
        }
    }

    public Brush ItemStatusColor
    {
        get { return itemStatusColor; }
        set
        {
            itemStatusColor = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ItemStatusColor");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}

public class Items
{
    List<ItemStatus> currentItemStatus;

    public List<ItemStatus> CurrentItemStatus
    {
        get { return currentItemStatus; }
        set { currentItemStatus = value; }
    }
}

public partial class DisplayItemStatus : Page
{
    ....
    ....

    public DisplayItemStatus()
    {
        foreach (Product product in lstProductList)
        {
            TextBlock tbItemStatus = new TextBlock();
            ....

            Items objItems = new Items();

            Binding bindingText = new Binding();
            bindingText.Source = objItems;
            bindingText.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            bindingText.Path = new PropertyPath(String.Format("ItemStatus"));
            tbItemStatus.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bindingText);

            Binding bindingColor = new Binding();
            bindingColor.Source = objItems;
            bindingColor.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            bindingColor.Path = new PropertyPath(String.Format("ItemStatusColor"));
            tbItemStatus.SetBinding(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, bindingColor);

            grdItemsList.Children.Add(tbItemStatus);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateItems_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int intCount = 0;

        List<Product> ProductList = new List<Product>();
        List<ItemStatus> ItemList = new List<ItemStatus>();

        ProductList = GetProducts();
        foreach (Product product in ProductList)
        {
            intCount++;
            UpdateStatus(intCount, ItemList);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateStatus(int intIndex, List<ItemStatus> ItemList)
    {
        ItemStatus status = new ItemStatus();
        status.ItemStatus = strOperationStatus;
        status.ItemStatusColor = brshForegroundColor;
        ItemList.Add(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a list of items and you are using TextBlock to display them? why not use a ListBox?

Comment: A lot of C# and no XAML... You are making things difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the specific problem here is that you're binding the TextBlock to an Item and not the ItemStatus. But you're also doing things the hard way, you really should do the binding details in XAML. Expose a collection of ItemStatus's from your view model, and have a ListBox or something with its ItemsSource bound to the collection. Then you'll need a DataTemplate which defines the TextBlock and the bindings to the ItemStatus.

[Here's a good walkthrough for it in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

Comment: Thanks all. I'm a beginner in WPF. Actually I had to skip a lot of code. So as per the current logic I had to create the TextBlocks dynamically. I had no other choice. Also the statuses are getting updated by a background process I think the link you provided is helpful. Let me try if I can use DataTemplate as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much THE GRAND USER. The link you provided me was so helpful. I have used DataTemplate, DataTriggers and ItemsControl. I had to change a lot in my code to use DataTemplate. But it helped me a lot.